# Why does numpy convert int to string and not string to int in a mixed array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

def printMe(myData):
    print(myData)
    print(type(myData))
    print("length = " + str(len(myData)))
    for x in myData:
        print(x)
        print(type(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myOtherData = np.array([123,"456"])
    printMe(myOtherData)
```

The output is

```
['123' '456']
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
length = 2
123
<class 'numpy.str_'>
456
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

Why does `123` get converted to a string rather than converting the `'456'` to an integer?

Comment: The authors of numpy designed it that way. Probably because int to str conversion can't fail unlike the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dtype` is not specified in the call `np.array` then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. In your example that will be a string.

Otherwise if you use `np.array([123,'456'], dtype=int)`, then it will try and force int type for all sequence members, this however will fail with value error if one of the members is not  suitable to be converted to the desired `dtype`.

Comment: Makes sense. It's different in np.genfromtxt() , where the non-numerics are converted to nan and the numerics are preserved.

Comment: The default `dtype` for `genfromtxt` is float.  `loadtxt` raises an error if it can't make the conversion. Both start with string data (from the file) and choose a general numeric dtype.